# Added more ADA on Yoroi while staking

Tags: wallet, staking, yoroi, rewards

I just added more ADA on my Yoroi Wallet while staking in a pool. Will the new ADA be automatically added into the current staking pool?

And do I need to withdraw my rewards in order to restake it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and to the same pool. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

New ADAs will be added to the pool automatically but they will not be considered for 1 epoch, because snapshot need to be submitted. You can check [here](https://viperstaking.com/ada-pools/staking-rewards-timeline) how the staking timeline works.

Rewards are automatically added to your wallet, you only need to withdraw if you want to spend them